# how to add listview data

Tags: android, listview

i want to add data to listview but my data are as String[] and arraylist is Planet[]
and when my code is like this i add only one item.

```
String[] zapasyList3 = ligy.split("<br/>");

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
planets = new Planet[] {  new Planet (zapasyList3[i])
          };  
        }

        ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

        // Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.
        listAdapter = new PlanetArrayAdapter(getBaseContext (), planetList);

        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks

Comment: post the code of the Planet class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
planets = new Planet[5];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    planets[i] = new Planet (zapasyList3[i]);
}  
//.. add the planets array now
```

You can also declare `planets` as ArrayList instead or regular array.. up to you.